# Adding sequential cells in a row after vlookup

Tags: excel

Is there another method of doing this calculation that will allow me to drag across cells and have the column index range adjust accordingly?

```
{=SUM(VLOOKUP(value,array,{1,2,3,4},0))}
```

The column index numbers unfortunately don't increase (ie. `{1,2,3,4} --> {2,3,4,5} etc..`) using this formula. Any suggestions on how to go about this without having to input manually?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use `COLUMN()` function that returns number of the current column that you called it.

> In column B : `Column() = 2`

And when you are using this function at your current format:

> In column K : `Column() = 11`

```
Column()- 11 + 1 = 1
Column()- 11 + 2 = 2
Column()- 11 + 3 = 3
Column()- 11 + 4 = 4
```

> Now with copying it to column L : `Column() = 12`

```
Column()- 11 + 1 = 2
Column()- 11 + 2 = 3
Column()- 11 + 3 = 4
Column()- 11 + 4 = 5
```